# VSCode Kivy 2.0.1 doesn't work (Unable to find a Window)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

I'm trying to work with Kivy on my computer using VSCode but i keep getting this error:

```
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.      
  File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

If someone knows how to solve this problem please explain to me how to solve it.

Comment: How did you install Kivy? Using pip?

Comment: Yes, i tried it with pip install

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Comment: @Panda50  do you use discord? we can talk there so i can explain better

Comment: @Pedro Schisler Squisati -Have you tried to run the same code in a system terminal outside of VSCode?

Comment: @JillCheng yes, still get the same error...